# CSS - style a link based on its "rel" attribute?

Tags: css, hyperlink

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="external"> LINK </a>
```

is it possible to add css rules for rel="external" ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Felix Kling and thirtydot suggested to use the `[att=val]` attribute selector (`a[rel="external"]`). **But** this will only work if `external` is the *only* `rel` value.

If you want to style links that could have 1 or more `rel` values, you should use the `[att~=val]` attribute selector:

`a[rel~="external"]` (note the [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) character)

An example for such a link could be:

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="external nofollow">LINK</a>
```

---

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation for the specification.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible with the [attribute selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html):

```
a[rel=external] {

}
```

**Note:** This is selector is [*not supported in IE6.*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t13)

Comment: it works :D I dont care about IE 6, my site doesn't even show up in that browser :x

Answer (score 4):

Use the [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector):

```
a[rel="external"] {
    color: red
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yUmJk/

Works in all modern browsers, and IE7+

Answer (score 1):

Possible with `*`.

```
// i.e: <a rel="nofollow external foo">
a[rel*="external"] { color:red; }

// you can add target attribute to open them in a new window
so.dom("a[rel*='external']").setAttr("target", "_blank");
```

Links:
http://github.com/qeremy/so
http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/attribute-selectors/