# Change the image of a div class by rel attribute

Tags: html, css, styles

Is there a way to select an element in CSS by class, then by the rel attribute? Thanks.

Comment: you're probably using rel incorrectly. Look at data  http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - style a link based on its "rel" attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608808/css-style-a-link-based-on-its-rel-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.class [rel="value"]` if it's a child, and 
`.class[rel="value"]`  if it's the [same element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).