# Targeting itemprop in CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following two sections of code generated by a Wordpress theme.
This first section of code is generated for a WP Page:

```
    <div class="postinner">
        <div itemprop="name">
            <h1 class="pagetitle">My Title</h1>
        </div>
        <p>First line of text</p>
        <p>Second line of text</p>
    </div>
```

This second section of code is generated for a WP Post:

```
    <div class="postinner">
        <article itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemscope="" role="article">
            <div itemprop="headline">
                <h1 class="pagetitle">Hello World!</h1>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

I cannot figure out the CSS selector to specifically target and center the text of the H1 tag within the "itemprop DIV" for the 1st section of code.

Also, I would also like to target and style the H1 tag in the WP Post with a different text color but again, cannot figure out CSS selector.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could try using CSS Attribute Selectors, such as:

```
div[itemprop="name"] h1 {
   color: red;
}
```

and:

```
div[itemprop="headline"] h1 {
   color: yellow;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bEUk8/

Comment: Thanks! Obviously works in jsfiddle. Not working in my WP theme though but think the theme is overwriting my custom CSS - will investigate further.

Comment: try with !important to override the style as in:

div[itemprop="name"] h1 {
   color: red !important;
}

Answer (score 12):

The `[att=val]` selector (as [suggested by Stuart Kershaw’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19778215/1591669)) works if the `itemprop` attribute has *only* this token as value.

But the [`itemprop` attribute can have multiple tokens as value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216506/1591669), in which case the `[att=val]` wouldn’t match anymore.

So you [might want to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924918/1591669) use the [`[att~=val]` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#attribute-representation), which matches in both cases: if it’s the only token or if it’s one of multiple tokens.

#### Example

Although both `span` elements have the `name` token as value of `itemprop`, only the first one is matched by the CSS rule with the `[itemprop="name"]` selector:

```css
[itemprop="name"] {font-size:200%;}
[itemprop~="name"] {color:red;}
```

```html
<div itemscope>
  <span itemprop="name">'name'</span>
  <span itemprop="name headline">'name' and 'headline'</span>
</div>
```