# target only determined links with a rel atribute

Tags: html, css, rel

I checked the special selection of input elements as shown [here](http://css-tricks.com/styling-texty-inputs-only/). I tried to apply this to select all links except a link which has a rel atribute. Here you have the example:

CSS

```
.language a:not[rel=author]{
    background: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="language">
   <a href="/en/">
       <abbr lang="en" title="english">EN</abbr>
   </a>
   <a href="/spa/">
       <abbr lang="es" title="english">ES</abbr>
   </a>
   <a href="http://whatever.com/" rel="author">Designed by me</a>
</section>
```

I would like only to target the first two links. I would like to avoid a class and try to target them with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
.language a:not([rel=author]){
    background: red;
}
```

You just forgot parentheses after :not

Answer (score 1):

Select all anchors that don't have a `rel` attribute:

```
.language a:not([rel]){
    background:#F00;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/bEwBA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just target the attribute...

```
.language a abbr[title="english"] {
   /* woohoo! */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `[att=val]` attribute selector, you should [use the `[att~=val]` attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924918/1591669):

```
.language a:not([rel~=author]){
    background: red;
}
```

`[rel~=author]` also matches if `author` is not the *only* value of the `rel` attribute. So it matches links like:

```
<a href="http://whatever.com/" rel="author">Designed by me</a>
<a href="http://whatever.com/" rel="author external">Designed by me</a>
<a href="http://whatever.com/" rel="author external nofollow">Designed by me</a>
<!-- … -->
```