# Apply CSS in Microdata + Schema.org?

Tags: css, schema.org, microdata

I like to apply CSS to match the text with the design in breadcrumbs.

For example:

```html
 <ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
› <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: (Note that the `›` character is not valid in this context, there can’t be no text as direct child of `ol`. I see that the example on Schema.org contains it; I’ll try to change it.)

Answer (score 2):

You can style elements with Microdata just like any other element, e.g. with an element selector (`ol {color:red;}`) or by adding `class` attributes in the HTML and using the class selector in CSS (`.breadcrumbs {color:red;}`).

If you want to make use of your existing Microdata attributes, you could use [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#attribute-selectors), for example:

- a `span` element that has the `itemprop` attribute:

  ```css
  span[itemprop] {color:red;}
  ```
- a `span` element that has the `itemprop` attribute with the value `name` (and no other value):

  ```css
  span[itemprop="name"] {color:red;}
  ```
- a `span` element that has the `itemprop` attribute with the value `name` ([and possibly other values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924918/1591669)):

  ```css
  span[itemprop~="name"] {color:red;}
  ```